# Fill a space evenly with light using a grid of point light sources

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Allright, so someone in the grower forum brought up the idea to fill up a grow space with a grid of small lights instead of a big overhead light.

I am familiar with basic algebra, but my math fu is not good enough for this:

Suppose I want an average light flow of 1000 micromol/s at any given point and one single light source emits 100 micromol at 10cm distance, how dense would my grid need to be?

Assume the walls of the box to be 90% reflective.

Comment: With 100% reflective walls, a single source would already effectively act as an infinite grid ... and contributes infinite light flow. Admittedly, after the first eight minutes, the effect is "only" that of a grid that reaches out for the distance of the Sun, but that is already pretty much.

Comment: Changed to 90% which is a reasonabĺe value for highly reflected paint. But then, there will be a plant in there =)